# Faceted search with WP-API data

Tags: terms, dropdown, wp-api

I have this site - where I have a post type called listings with a number of custom taxonomies and terms. - http://scd.blaze.wpengine.com/

If you choose a region it then shows you listings that are in a taxonomy called `listing_area` and you can then filter them using the FacetWp plugin by `listing facilities` and `listing_shooting_type`

I then have this site - http://dev.5874.co.uk/scd-data/

Where I am pulling in data from the first site using WP-API and AngularJs.

I have got to a point where I can show listings by `listing_area` and `listing_shooting_type` But they all show in the same list and the dropdowns are not connected.

What I need to do is find a way to use these dropdowns (or a better way if needed) to display data that applies to both dropdown choices. For example if `NorthWest` and `AirRifleAirPistol` are both selected, just show all listings that are in the custom term `northwest` and `airrifleairpistol`.

Here is a JSFiddle showing all my code for the external site, please let me know if I haven't explained this properly or provided the right code, I'm super stuck with this so any help would be very much appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/k5rg8Lgj/

Comment: Looks like a pure Javascript problem, which will be off-topic here per the [help].

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for letting me know, I thought maybe as I was using WP-API someone might have experience with it, but I will head over to stackoverflow and see :)

Comment: I have provided an answer to the wp-api side, which was relevant. However, you need to change your javascript for angular to just have one ajax call and combine the filter types as per the answer I gave

Answer (score 0):

The correct format for filters in the url is:

`?filter[listing_area]=northwest&filter[listing_shooting_type]=clay`

You don't need to create one ajax call per option, just one which combines the filters as set by the user